# How do I pop to a specific previous window in Titanium?

Tags: window, titanium, appcelerator

I have pushed the Window from

> **A->B->C->D**

Where D is Final Window from there I have to go back to window **A**. How I will do it in titanium?

Comment: you really need to provide more information here

Comment: i have also Need this. but no an solution yet...

Comment: See , I navigating Through these Window When Final Window came i don't want back by navigation all the way .What i want is from Last Window To come on First Window.Please tell like what more info you want???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use fireEvent for that like

just add this code into your B window

```
  Ti.App.addEventListener('closeWinB',function(e){
    B.close();
});
```

and write below code when you want to redirect to window A

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('closeWinB');
```

hope it will work for you....

Comment: Thanks For replying!!!.I did this.but this was working on simulator but not on device.On device it takes me randomly with in these page.Please tell me any other solution.Thanks

Comment: i said i did this means like follow the backtrack Chaine of FireEvent.

Comment: just take one array in app.js and then each window your are create just add this win to the array...and at win D close each window...this is best way and i am currently using this way.

Comment: and don't forgot to set your array as Ti.app.array = yourarr    so by this you can access your array at win D.

Comment: I will do what you have told, because of short time i did by overriding back button as per my project.I will update you when i will do.Thank a lot for replying!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use views instead of windows.

Create a window like this:

```
var PAC = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'PAC',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
```

Create your view as "other screen" or a new window.
You can achieve this using the full screen pixel size or a relative unit as 100%

```
var viewInputData = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    width:'800px',
    height:'600px',
    zIndex:1
});

var viewOutputData = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    zIndex:0

});
```

Please note the zIndex value, the zIndex value is how "at the top" a view should be placed.
In this case, viwOutputDaata is below viewInputData.

Create a button to fire the event.
This window will switch the zIndex value which will show the value of the textfield:

```
var  viewInputDataButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    width:120,
    height:111,
    top:10,
    backgroundImage: 'bp/images/square_button_1010.jpg',
    backgroundSelectedImage : 'bp/images/square_button_1001.jpg'
});

// declare a input view where your data will live
var viewInputNombre=Ti.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    backgroudColor: 'white',
    top: 250,
    font: {fontsize: 80, fontWeight: 'arial'},
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth:5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius:3,
    height:50,
    width: 170

});

// add input to view 
viewInputData.add(viewInputNombre);
```

Now create and add the button of the next view

```
var  viewOutputDataButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    width:120,
    height:111,
    top:10,
    backgroundImage: 'bp/images/square_button_1001.jpg',
    backgroundSelectedImage : 'bp/images/square_button_1010.jpg'
});

// Create a simple label
var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'I am View 2',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

// add label to view 
viewOutputData.add(label2);
```

Here is how you switch the two views using the zIndex attribute.
Create the event listener for the button at view1 which takes care of this switch:

```
viewInputDataButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    label2.setText(viewInputNombre.getValue());
    viewOutputData.setZIndex(viewInputData.zIndex+1); // zIndex change
});
```

The secret is, you know the view at button 1 is "on top" and has the "max zindex"
so.. you add the zIndex above the current zIndex of the focued view, and you pop the view 
to the top...

```
viewOutputDataButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    viewInputData.setZIndex(viewOutputData.zIndex+1);
});
```

Same here, the button just returns to the original window...

```
// add buttons
viewInputData.add(viewInputDataButton);
viewOutputData.add(viewOutputDataButton);

// add the views to the window
PAC.add(viewInputData);
PAC.add(viewOutputData);

// open it... 
PAC.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you structured your application, you could typically do something similar to as follows:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    A.open({
        animated: true
    )}
})
```